# pulsing red status bar when my app is not in the background (voice over ip)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When you add voice over ip support for your app with AVAudioSession a pulsing red status bar appears when your app goes into background and is recording something. Apple app called Voice memos has this red status bar inside their app, is it possible to do the same? It works in the background but i want it in the app.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could `class-dump` `UIKit` and look for `UIApplication`.
There are private APIs for doing that, as explained in [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=Sk5V6jqk8sQC&lpg=PA74&ots=YcdQB4HREc&pg=PA74#v=onepage&f=false).

Comment: Note that if you use private APIs, your app is unlikely to pass the App Store approval process.